# Recover Ubuntu file owners after improper use of chown

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, sudo, chown

I made the mistake of changing the owner with the command

***sudo chown -R userG: userG /***

Now MySQL and other things not working, I try to repair but the ** sudo ** command does not work

Give this error

***sudo: / usr / bin / sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set***

Consultation is it possible to repair this system without dying in the attempt ???

In UBUNTU it is possible through some command or script.

It is an Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS server

Apache does work, not MySQL. I have some applications in php

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/452860/693277

Answer (score 0):

You can boot off a DVD or a USB stick and start the live version of the OS.  Once you are there you can then access the Linux partition and run "sudo chgrp".  However, this assumes you know the correct values which may be different in different directories. (Your note indicates you've changed the permission of system applications, which can be fatal.) You can find those values if you have access to another similar system and then use that system as a pattern. Once you have that info you can build scripts that will have one command for each directory that is different.

If this were my system I would boot into the live version and then copy the data to another place, such as another disk or USB disk.  Once that's done you would have to re-install the OS on your disk, configure the applications, and bring the data over with whatever changes are necessary.  I should warn you that I've been a UN*X admin since 1985 but have used LINUX only sparingly until I recently starting using Ubuntu Studio as my primary desktop OS.